# text and button are not aligned inside card-list

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I'm building a mobile application using Ionic. I'm having trouble getting the button after the text aligned inside my card-list.

**The Code:**

```
<div>
  {{ match.location }} <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-information-outline"></button>
</div>
```

**I'm seeing the following**

[image]

Comment: Add just simple css `.button{vertical-align:middle;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's causing the issue?

This issue is because of the fact that the `button` class has a high value for `line-height` and `min-height`.

> The solution

**Option 1**

You can add the following CSS to the button

```
button{

  line-height:0!important;
  min-height:0!important;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/8f84f30e7998)

**Option 2**

Alternatively, remove the button class and only have the `button-icon` class.In this case, you do not need to add a style for `button-icon`.

Here is a [demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/28fd66dd8129)

Comment: Thanks I went with option 2 and that resolved the issue. I appreciate the clear explanation and the demos of the various options.